# Tool to Convert one table script in accordance to another

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, alter-table

Asking for a suggestion: I have a table script like :

```
CREATE TABLE  PER_ADDR
   (    "ADDRESS_ID" NUMBER(18,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "EFFECTIVE_START_DATE" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "EFFECTIVE_END_DATE" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "BUSINESS_GROUP_ID" VARCHAR2(264), 
    "ADDRESS_LINE_1" VARCHAR2(240), 
    "ADDRESS_LINE_2" VARCHAR2(240), 
    "ADDRESS_LINE_3" VARCHAR2(240), 
    "ADDRESS_LINE_4" VARCHAR2(240), 
    "BUILDING" VARCHAR2(240), 
    "FLOOR_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(40)
)
```

This is part of one patch. 
and another one

```
 CREATE TABLE  XX_PER_ADDR
       (    "ADDRESS_NUM" NUMBER(18,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "EFFECTIVE_START_DATE" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "EFFECTIVE_END_DATE" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "BUSINESS_GROUP_ID" VARCHAR2(264), 
        "ADDRESS_LINE_1" VARCHAR2(240), 
        "ADDRESS_LINE_2" VARCHAR2(240), 
        "ADDRESS_LINE_3" VARCHAR2(240), 
        "ADDRESS_LINE_4" VARCHAR2(240), 
        "BUILDING" VARCHAR2(240), 

    )
```

I have to change 1st query of `PER_ADDR to XX_PER_ADDR` that is `ADDRESS_ID` should be changed to `ADDRESS_NUM`.right now i am doing it manually via excel. Is there any tool to do this. For example to convert `PER_ADDR to XX_PER_ADDR` i will have to write :

```
alter table PER_ADDR
DROP (FLOOR_NUMBER,ADDRESS_ID);

ALTER TABLE PER_ADDR
ADD(ADDRESS_NUM NUMBER(18,0) NOT NULL ENABLE);
```

Is there any other tool or any other workaround as there are 52 such table comparisons

Comment: You can use the rename function.  So - alter table per_addr rename column address_id to address_num;.

Answer (score 1):

simple Linux sed command will do the job , eg :

```
cat your_script_file |sed 's/ADDRESS_ID/ADDRESS_NUM/g' > your_new_script_file
```

Comment: what will this do ??

Comment: Replace the token with new one and create new file with the

Comment: That include rhe new name

Comment: I need the alter scripts for this actually